# how to check that a file or dir is a 'system' file or dir

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt, pyside

`QDir::entryList()` allows listing 'system' files and dirs using `QDir::System` and 'hidden' files and dirs using `QDir::Hidden` flag. If I already know file path, I can check if the file is hidden using `QFileInfo::isHidden()`. But is there something similar for 'system' files? Something like hypothetical `QFileInfo::isSystem()`? In other words, such a function should return `true` for items which are returned using `QDir::System` flag in `QDir::entryList()` and `false` otherwise.

Comment: What do you mean by a "system file"?

Comment: I mean the file which are selected by `QDir::System` flag in `QDir::entryList()`. I am not sure what exactly it is as the documentation is very vague on this point.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there isn't. Your best chance is to use `QDir::entryList()` with `nameFilters` set to the path and the `filters` flags set to `QDir::System`. If the returned list is empty then that path isn't a system file as defined by `QDir::System`.